# image assets catalog and iOS device family

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-universal-app, asset-catalog, uiimageasset

[image: asset catalog]

I have set the app for only iPhone but if I keep the images at Universal will it be used for iPhone

This is very much confusing please guide

Comment: Universal means that iPhone and iPad can use those images. If you only put to iPhone the iPad can't use the image.

Answer (score 1):

Nope, You cannot do so. If you are targeting Universal Apps (iPhones + iPads) then App store need assets/images for both. Thus while uploading app to App Store it will show error saying "Missing assets".